# Having a handset and tablet layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I read through the android doc about [supporting both](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html) but what is not really explained is how will you know when to call the activity for a phone and an activity for a tablet?

What I mean by that is lets say on a tablet I have 2 fragments, a list view and some other fragment that changes based on the list view click. Now on a phone I obviously don't want that tablet view because everything would be too compact so I would want to start an activity with a list view then go to another activity with the other fragment.

I know about the different layout folders types and I already use that i.e. `layout`,`layout-sw600dp`,`layout-sw720dp` to call that layout across screen sizes but the regular layout view does not have all parts because thats the phone layout so how do I handle that?

Comment: This blog post will also help. Like supporting layouts for different screen sizes, you can also have layouts that support different versions of android. So for tablets, you can have layout-v11 (Android 3.0) and store your layouts in that folder. You can use the presence of fragments in the layout to differentiate which device the app is running on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google [I/O app](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) is a good example. Basically you have different layouts that contain different Fragments for different devices. Since each Fragment manages itself like an Activity you don't have to do much beyond creating layouts of fragments.

There is also a nice [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGIU2JX1U5Y) that explains a lot about that app.